# MongoDB - Maintain data integrity automatically

Tags: mongodb

I'm interested in migrating from a relational DB to MongoDB for the performance improvements.  I would be storing redundant, denormalized data in multiple locations and am wondering if it is possible to automatically maintain the integrity of data WITHOUT application code.

For example, if I have a User document...

```
User: { _id: "...", userName: "johndoe", displayName: "John Doe", TotalTasks: 3 }
```

And then a Task document...

```
Task: { _id "...", title: "Finish Reports", userID: "...", userName: "johndoe", userDiplayName: "John Doe" }
```

How can I automatically ensure that userName and displayName stay the same in the appropriate documents?  How can I ensure that TotalTasks is updated when new tasks are added or deleted for this user?

Comment: You should redesign your schema according to NoSQL principles. Tasks should be embedded in user documents if possible. I don't think the answer you accepted to your question actually answers it appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't enforce these constraints on the server side. However triggers are something that's [planned](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124). The only constraint that's currently supported is unique indexes.

Comment: I was hoping for something more like an auto-updating materialized view... something like how CouchDD works.  I guess this is the best solution I'll be able to find though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't enforce them with MongoDB without some outside application coding.  The one question I would have above, is why not have Tasks be part of the user document?  That would eliminate your consistency issue as you would be able to handle the user and task atomically.

However, assuming you can't, What I have done in the past is use MySQL and a version field to enforce consistency.  Each app is different, but the basic gist is as follows:

1) each doc in Mongo has a related row in MySQL.  This row in MySql will have the collection, the id of the doc and some auditing info (last changed, who changed, etc.)
2) determine what docs you need to lock and then create a serializable transaction in mysql.
3) update the records in mongo using a Find and update and make sure the version field matches to enforce optimistic concurrency.
4) if everything completes, then commit the transaction in mysql.
5) if something goes wrong, rollback all the operations in mongo that completed.  If a rollback can't be completed, shove the info to rollback into a messagequeue and have a separate process that "cleans" up.
6) roll back the mysql transaction

This has to be used sparingly since it adds a lot of overhead to your operations, however, if you embed your documents as I described with the user -> task, you should find that you don't really need to use this except in some outside cases or bulk updates.

Comment: Quick question: If you were to make all the tasks part of the user document, does that mean that every time you need attributes of the user (but not the actual tasks), for example when you want to get the users email address to send an email, will this not cause significant overhead as Mongo will get the entire document, including possibly 1000s of tasks? Or even just to perform a query on it?

Comment: If this is a problem I guess you could just store the object IDs of all the tasks in the user document, but then you would need to perform two queries for getting a certain task for a certain user...right? (I may very well be wrong in both cases, since I have only shortly played around with Mongo)